# Убрать border на активной вкладке (ссылке)

Tags: html, css

Есть код - слайдер на библиотеке Tiny Carousel, в котором все ссылки (а именно: "Разработка сайтов", "Контекстная реклама","Реклама в соц. сетях") с `border-bottom`. Можно ли сделать так, что бы на активной вкладке (ссылке) не было `border-bottom`?

```css
.ssilka {

  width: 235px;

  height: 24px;

  text-align: center;

  float: left;

  font-weight: bold;

  margin: 25px 20px 0 60px;

  font-family: proximabold;

  font-size: 1.8em;

  color: #2b2a2a !important;

  border-bottom: 4px dashed #d3d3d3;

}
```

```html
<style>
  #slider1 {
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
  }
  #slider1 .viewport {
    width: 947px;
    height: 386px;
    margin: 80px 40px;
  }
  #slider1 .overview li {
    height: 386px;
    width: 947px;
    border: medium none;
  }
  #slider1 .overview li > img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 386px !important;
    width: 947px !important;
  }
</style>

  <div class="ssilka"><a href="#" id="gotoslide1">Разработка сайтов</a></div>
  <div class="ssilka"><a href="#" id="gotoslide2">Контекстная реклама</a></div>
  <div class="ssilka"><a href="#" id="gotoslide3">Реклама в соц. сетях</a></div>

<div id="slider1">
  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
      <li>
        <img src="/123.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="/222.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="/321.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы применять какие-то дополнительные стили к активной ссылке, нужно чтобы эта ссылка при активности получала какой-то класс, но, судя по вашему коду, этого не происходит, поэтому можно с помощью `jquery` добавлять класс `active` к активной ссылке:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.ssilka', function(){
    $('.ssilka').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

а при помощи css добавлять правило для того, чтобы убирать бордер у активной ссылки:

```
.ssilka.active {
  border: 0;
}
```

И ниже совокупный пример с вашими стилями, только для ссылок:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.ssilka', function() {
    $('.ssilka').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
 .ssilka {
   width: 235px;
   height: 24px;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 25px 20px 0 60px;
   font-family: proximabold;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #2b2a2a !important;
   border-bottom: 4px dashed #d3d3d3;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 .ssilka.active {
   border: 0;
 }
 .ssilka a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ssilka active"><a href="#" id="gotoslide1">Разработка сайтов</a>
</div>
<div class="ssilka"><a href="#" id="gotoslide2">Контекстная реклама</a>
</div>
<div class="ssilka"><a href="#" id="gotoslide3">Реклама в соц. сетях</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но почему то не получается, теперь когда я нажимаю на ссылку, страница перепрыгивает к самому началу, как будто я на неё установил якорь. Может конфликт библиотек или еще что то?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить следующее правило на активной ссылке

```
   text-decoration: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, думал что делают наоборот, при наведении. 
Но все же:

```
.ssilka:active //это активная
{
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.ssilka a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```